# Force render a 360 video in Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine

So I am working on a project and I would like it to be a 360 video. The issue is eevee currently doesn't support 360 rendering. Is there anyway I could get passed this? Maybe rendering a reflection or a cube map? I would need this to be an animation so it would be a hard manually rendering frame by frame.

Would I be able to code a script that renders to a 360?

Thanks for the help! :)